# send mails via swift mailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I try to send a mail via swiftmailer and my code is :

```
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($template, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($from);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');
//$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('D:/file.txt'));
// send message
if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures)) {
```

but the problem is I recieve an empty message ! $template is a variable which contains html code !

Comment: Have you tried printing out `$template` to be shure it's not empty?

Comment: yap ! I printed it before setbody() function ! it's ok !

Answer (score 2):

Forget about $failures parameter. Just use a try catch !

```
try 
{
    //... all of your code
    $swift->send($message);
}
catch(Exception $exception)
{
    //A big object containing the error message
    print_r($exception);
}
```